# Android Studio - Cannot run tests because java can't be found?

Tags: java, android, macos, gradle

I'm unable to run my unit tests that I was previously able to in Android Studio, and I am totally lost. Here's the error that's thrown:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java"": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Some background:
I think there is a chance that this has to do with the fact that I was previously trying to run gradle from the command line. Since this is a new machine, gradle complained that there was no java install. Further, `$ java -verison` would bring up the Mac system dialog prompting me to install Java. So, I installed java via homebrew and symlinked it into `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`, and java began being picked up from the command line.

Worried that this was creating my issue, I removed the homebrew installation and symlinks, prompting command line invocations of java/gradle to start complaining again.

My final attempt at a fix was to set the Android Studio jdk as `JAVA_HOME`, but I'm still getting this error.

I can build apps and the APK just fine, but tests won't run no matter what I try. Any shred of insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

I faced similar issue. Remove whitespace from your path. Rename `Android Studio.app` to `AndroidStudio.app`. That worked for me.

Comment: I tried this and even uninstalling AS to make sure the embedded JDK path was correct, AS said it was not a valid JDK location unfortunately

Comment: This worked for me, I was facing issue "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java"": error=2, No such file or directory"

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I thought the issue was caused by a combination of junit5/mockk in my project, turns it out it was just a white space after all. Better be reading logs starting from the root next time)

Comment: Wow I can't believe it works. Updated to android dolphin and I was having this issue. Thanks

Comment: if anyone is confused, close android studio->go to applications, rename "Android Studio" to "AndroidStudio"-> open project -> locate jre again and it should point to correct jdk location

Comment: Can't believe it worked for me too. Thanks !

Comment: Back here for the second time after the Flamingo update. Seems to be worth writing a script for this D: